# ASP.NET: Maintain variable value after session expires

Tags: asp.net, session, session-timeout

I'm developing a website in which the session must expire in 15 minutes.  After 15 minutes, the user's redirected to another page once they click any buttons.  My problem however, is after the session expires, there's one value in an integer variable I need to maintain.

What's the best way to keep this value after session expiration?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to put that value on some persistent medium may be database or some file on the disk.

Answer (score 1):

If the value isn't anything secure (like login name or role ID, etc) you could put it in a cookie.  Just beware that cookies are easy to tamper-with.

Answer (score 0):

This is one option. You can maintain this Int into `ViewState`, but keep in mind that every page has its own `ViewState` and you cant access one page's ViewState on other page.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store for same page you can use ,either viewstate or static varialbes , or you can compromise with security and store data in cookies ,relaible method is to store data in database and delete it by using triggers on some events